# Remove vertical scrollbar for textarea in bootstrap modal - css jquery c# .net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am feeding values to the bootstrap modal through jquery (from my database). The form values changes from one row to multiple rows. I dont want the scrollbar. I want the textarea element to increase its height to fit the content. How can I do this? below is my html,

```
 <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-form-label">Background:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control bg" disabled> </textarea>
```

I am using below jquery to feed value into my text area,

```
$('#Modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
     var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal  
     var back = button.data('back')
     var modal = $(this)
     modal.find($('.bg')).val(back);
```

Now the text area appears with vertical scrollbar which I want to avoid. I want the text area to automatically increase its height to fit the content.

I cannot use other than "Textarea" element since that is the only element that holds the content formating.

Tried fetching scrollheight of above bg class but it returns zero. I guess it is not fetching value of the textarea after executing above jquery element.

I am working on this for more than 5 hours but couldnt find a solution. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Setting overflow to hidden doesn't work?

Comment: no it didnt. :( it removes the scrollbar but not displaying the whole content it cuts of

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution by using 2 modal triggers. Bootstrap has "show.bs.modal" event which gets fired immediately after clicking a button (which opens the modal) and bootstrap has another even called "shown.bs.modal" which gets fired after the modal is shown. So i split my code like below to fit the content within textarea.

```
$('#Modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
     var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal  
     var back = button.data('back')
     var modal = $(this)
     modal.find($('.bg')).val(back);
});

$('#Modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
     var hg = $('.bg').prop('scrollHeight');
     var modal = $(this)
     modal.find($('.bg')).height(hg);
});
```

For some unknown reason scrollheight is increasing every time I open the modal and the size is not reducing the textarea to fit smaller content. So to overcome this issue, i am manually setting height of the textarea to zero before assigning the new height. Below is the changed code,

```
$('#Modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var modal = $(this);
            modal.find($('.bg')).height(0);
            var hg = $('.bg').prop('scrollHeight');                
            modal.find($('.bg')).height(hg);
});
```